# How to prevent auto scroll in RecyclerView after notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with several items types. It looks like this:

- 07/21/2017
- Message 1
- Message 2
- Message 3
- 07/22/2017
- Message 4
- New messages header
- Message 5
- Message 6

When new messages arrived I sort it by date and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It works well, but it automatically scroll my `RecyclerView` on new item(s) height. In this case I cannot use `notifyItemInserted()` because I don't know item position after sorting.

How to force `RecyclerView` do not scroll after `notifyDataSetChanged()` without call `notifyItemInserted()`?

Comment: Just wonder Why you don't want to call notifyItemInserted() ?

Comment: Because I sort items by date and don't know inserted item position(s) after sorting.

Comment: And your views can be changed from the beginning item, is that right?

Comment: Yes, if new item has smallest date.

Answer (score 12):

There are 4 ways you can try. Because I don't know what is the height of your view, so I can't sure if it really works. But let give it a try

**I.** You don't which specific item could be changed. But you know the range of that change

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);                 
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size());
```

**II.** Clear list before call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
yourList.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**III.** Save/Reset state of `ReyclerView` before/after adding new item

```
    // Save state
    private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
    recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();

    // Restore state
    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```

**IV.** Use this function

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size());
```

Comment: First method is great, exactly what I need!

Comment: Bingo! solution # III worked for me while also using DiffUtil in my adapter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you played with `myRecView.getLayoutManager().setStackFromEnd(boolean)` ?

If you can determine if the new item has been inserted after sorting above or below the visible part and in function of this call `setStackFromEnd ()` with true or false maybe you can avoid the scroll.

I do not know if it will really work ....

Answer (score 0):

You can know where the new item has been inserted using `list.indexOf(yourItem)` on your list of items. Then you can call `notifyItemInserted()`